# custom add to cart button using ajax not rendering top minicart in magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, ajax, mini-cart

I have created quick order functionality on custom page layout .

Process like below:

customer find product in textbox and display matching products in autocomplete.In autocomplete result displays product-name,image and add to cart button.when I click add-to-cart button ,ajax call in custom created controller and I created code for programmatically add-to-cart product.Product add to cart successfully via my ajax code but mincart not render on top but when I refresh page then it displays products in minicart.

Anything missing in this process ?
And How to render minicart in controller OR Anyone tell me where is code in magento 2 of minicart render after add to cart ajax  ?
I need a hint for this.please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the file `module_dir/etc/frontend/sections.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="your/controller/action">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```